# Vue 2 and Webpack Mix: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: jquery, vuejs2

I've had problems getting [Vue Bootstrap Date Time Picker](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker) working, and succeeded last night.

I had to prepend the other items in the `webpack.mix.js` file with:

```
mix.autoload({
    'jquery': ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
    'vue': ['Vue','window.Vue'],
    'moment': ['moment','window.moment']
})...
```

... and then I removed the various references to jQuery from within the HTML of the views in Blade.

However, I found this broke `this.$http.get` elsewhere in the application.

In the `app.js` file I'm using:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue';

import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

Vue.use(VueResource);
```

I've seen various other examples for this arrangement, but none of them make a difference.

I made a tweak to the method triggering the error in the component I'm accessing:

```
this.$http.get('/api/method?name=value').then(function (response) { ...
```

... removing `=>` and adding `function` but that also made no difference.

I installed jQuery for Node and then amended `app.js`:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
```

... but this changed nothing.

I know this is a problem that's been covered before, but having tried the alternatives with no success, I had to reach out for assistance.

Comment: is it necessary to load `'vue': ['Vue','window.Vue'],` in mix autoload? `this` already refers to the global Vue instance. I suggest removing it and try again, as it's probably messing with your global Vue instance

Comment: @JacobGoh I'd suspected as much and having removed it, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Try your luck with vue-axios?

Comment: Someone did suggest that, but I've not used Axios before, and time is a bit constrained at the moment.

Comment: It's almost the same as vue resources. If u tried it and it still fails, then u can know for sure that the global Vue instance is problematic.